# having troubles with animation memory in android for images

Tags: android, image, memory, animation, view

guys am having some troubles with running out of memory when displaying an animation for some reason the system seems to be holding all of the images at once, is there maybe a way to tell it to hold only one image at once, here is the code am using and am linking it to an image view, here is a lil part of the code is basically the same just with many more images, thank you

```
    <animation-list xmlns:
   android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:oneshot="false">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image5" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image6" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image7" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image8" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image9" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image10" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you decrease the file size of the images, either by making the smaller in size or changing to a different file format, like jpg. If this doesn't work out, add this to your application tag in the manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: but i thought the android team discourages that idea because of making the application slower?

Comment: it isn't recommended. That's why you should decrease the file size of your images first, and see if that works out.

Comment: I did but it is over 200 images and its loosing too much resolution :( i was hoping there was a way to trick the system into just holding one image at a time?

Comment: am trying to create a perfect loop for beach scene

Comment: jpg is smaller. there is little else you can do besides setting it to a large heap or making your own animation class that handles the queueing better